# Using binary variable with low variance in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures

I am trying to design a repeated measures study where a person makes a choice (yes vs no). On the next trial they are asked to make a yes vs no choice on a different question. I want to test if the response in the previous trial will affect the what choice is selected in trial 2. Would a logistic regression work for this? I'm assuming distribution of choices will be very skewed towards the yes choice on trial 1 and I'm worried I won't have enough variance to detect a real effect. Is there an alternative test I could perform to analyze this?

Comment: Chisquare test?

Comment: Assuming I want to control for continuous predictors or use mediation chi square would not work right? Also, can using the previous choice with low variance in response be okay with chi square? I dont think it can if I remember right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you need to account for the correlation in the repeated measurements of each subject. Options are to use a Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) approach, Alternating Logistic Regression (ALR) and a mixed effects logistic regression (GLMM).

The GEE and ALR provide you with coefficients with a marginal/population interpretation, whereas the GLMM approach with coefficients that have an interpretation conditional on the subject. Most often you want the coefficients with marginal interpretation. If you fit a GLMM, you can also get marginal coefficients in second step by applying a transformation.

If you have missing data (i.e., some persons do not responding in the second trial), the GLMM approach would be preferable, because it will provide you correct results under the missing at random assumption (whereas GEE and ALR under the missing completely at random assumption).